# "Could not establish link to the H2O cloud http://127.0.0.1:54321 after 20 retries" when importing h2o

Tags: python, azure, h2o

I installed h2o for Python 2 using below code in Azure Notebook IDE:

```
!pip install h2o
```

Then imported it using:

```
import h2o
```

However, I get the following error:

```
H2OConnectionError: Could not establish link to the H2O cloud      http://127.0.0.1:54321 after 20 retries
[07:03.57] H2OServerError: HTTP 503 Service Unavailable:
[07:04.78] H2OServerError: HTTP 503 Service Unavailable:
[07:05.99] H2OServerError: HTTP 503 Service Unavailable:
```

Can I get some help from anyone please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to slightly reformat the question and add the azure tag.

Comment: Hi,any progress now? Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem seems to be that the port **54321** is even locally blocked by Windows.

Just try to start it on the *normally* open port **8080**.

`h2o.init(ip="127.0.0.1", port="8080")`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to import `h2o` in the jupyter notebook locally and it works for me.Please refer to my steps as below:

Step1: Follow the [doc](http://jupyter.org/install) to installing Jupyter with pip ,then run the notebook locally.

[image]

Step2: Download h2o zip from this [link](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wolpert/2/index.html) and install it with the `.whl` file.

[image]

Step3: Create Terminal and run the command: `java -jar h2o.jar`.

[image]

[image]

Step 4: Create Python2 notebook and run the python code.

[image]

---

I also create `h2o` cluster on my vm then access it via my azure notebook.

Please use `h2o.init(ip="<your vm ip>")` to specify the IP address of the access.

[image]

*Don't forger open port `'54321'` in the Network security group(it's important!).

Hope it helps you.